# Can we create CLLocation updates on background thread?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Hi in my iOS app I should fetch CLLocation updates in a background thread hence I have created CLLocation object like follows

```
  dispatch_queue_t globalConcurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(globalConcurrentQueue,^{

 objAppDelegate.locationManager.DistanceFilter =Constants.kDISTANCE_FILTER;
                            objAppDelegate.locationManager.DesiredAccuracy =CLLocation.AccurracyBestForNavigation;
                            objAppDelegate.locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation ();

    });
```

Is it okay? I read it on some portal, as per apple guidelines we should call CLLocation updates strictly on Main thread, Is that so?

Comment: [Looks like](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/cllocationmanager-and-thread-safety/) the manager needs to be created on the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to call the `locationManager` from a background thread, most of its call are asynchronous.  So it is best to call it from the main thread though not required.  Also, it is important to note that whatever thread you start the 'locationmanager' from is the thread its delegates will be called on.

As per the docs:

> The methods of your delegate object are called from the thread in which you started the corresponding location services. That thread must itself have an active run loop, like the one found in your application’s main thread.